# Building Python interface to custom CGAL function

Tags: python, c++, swig, cgal

I'm trying to build a python interface to a custom CGAL function. The function works just fine on its own, but I get errors when I try to do the linking with Python using SWIG.

I have been using 'cgal_create_cmake_lists' to create the CMakeLists.txt for the CGAL part, doing cmake and make, and then using the generated .o files to link with SWIG, but I think I am not linking the required boost and GMP libraries properly with the SWIG-generated shared object ".so" file.

SWIG generates the shared object files for me, but then when I try to import my module, I get an error:

Symbol not found: __ZN4CGAL11NULL_VECTORE

I am using the command "ld -bundle -flat_namespace -undefined suppress -o cgal_executable.so *.o"  to generate the shared object file. Should I be linking boost and GMP libraries in this step? If so, how do I do that? I am on a Mac OS. I can share my full code if needed.

I know there is a project for Python-SWIG bindings, but I really don't need all of it, and also it seems to be missing a lot of useful CGAL features. I would like to work in C++, and just interface my functions with Python as needed.

Comment: `__ZN4CGAL11NULL_VECTORE` is `CGAL::NULL_VECTOR`, you should be linking with CGAL (`-lCGAL`). Or use the header-only mode (see the doc).

Comment: Actually I was doing that already, and I have finally resolved the problem. It seems I must include '-flat_namespace' when I build the shared object file. Do you know why that is?